# Bash: Wrap Long Lines Inside the Same Column

Tags: bash, formatting

I would like to create a table with two columns. The first column contains the key name and the second column contains the value. The value can be text that usually results in multiple lines in the terminal.

With `printf` or `column` I can easily get the following output:

```
<----- Terminal Length ------>
key1     This is the value for
key1 with a very long text. 
...
```

But I would like the value to be displayed in the same column like this:

```
<----- Terminal Length ------>
key1     This is the value for
         key1 with a very long
         text.
...
```

How can I wrap a long line inside the same column?

Comment: You can use `tput cols` to get the # of columns in the terminal, and then insert newlines and padding yourself, but there might be an easier way.

Comment: Thx @andlrc, this was a key piece to script a solution. Though I also hope for a more generic (more than two columns) and existing solution.

Comment: @andlrc: Sorry, didn't intend to snatch away your answer. If there is no better alternative, you can submit your own answer, I will delete mine, and accept yours.

Comment: You didn't snatch my answer. I informed you about a possible, but, as you also pointed out; a not so portable way to archive it. You actually wrote the code! I'm happy that I could provide some information/help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the util-linux 'column' command can do it. It is very versatile.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<- EOF | column --separator '|' \
                     --table \
                     --output-width 30 \
                     --table-noheadings \
                     --table-columns C1,C2 \
                     --table-wrap C2
key1|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
key2|blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhzzz
EOF
```

This gives :

```
key1  Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
      et, consectetur adipisci
      ng elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut lab
      ore et dolore magna aliq
      ua.
key2  blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
      hhhhhhhzzz
```

`--output-width` : give desired size (can use 'tput cols' as described above)

`--table-columns C1,C2` : give names to columns to be used with other options

`--table-wrap C2` : wrap column 2

Column version :

```
# column -V
column from util-linux 2.33.1
```

Comment: What version of `column` is this? My installation of Ubuntu shipped with a BSD `column`, and it doesn't support  these options.

Comment: version added - it's from the util-linux package 2.33.1

Comment: This is the actual answer

Comment: The better column https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098248/how-can-i-install-the-util-linux-version-of-the-column-command-in-18-04

Answer (score 3):

Solution based on andlrc's comment:

```
columnize2 () { 
    indent=$1; 
    collen=$(($(tput cols)-indent)); 
    keyname="$2"; 
    value=$3; 
    while [ -n "$value" ] ; do 
        printf "%-10s %-${indent}s\n" "$keyname" "${value:0:$collen}";  
        keyname="";
        value=${value:$collen}; 
    done
}

longvalue=---------------------------------------------------------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
columnize2 30 key1 $longvalue
key1       --------------------------------------------------
           -------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzz
```

`tput cols` returns the amount of characters per line in the terminal window. We use this to determine how many characters of the value we can print per line (`collen`). If it does not fit on one line, the rest is printed on the following lines.
`%-10s` in the print statement is used to allocate 10 characters to display the keyname (long keys are not handled well). 
`%-${indent}s` is used to indent the value by #indent characters.
Only print as many characters of the value as will fit on one line:`${value:0:$collen}` and strip the already printed characters from the value `value=${value:$collen}`
For following lines we don't print the keyname (by setting it to an empty string).

Comment: You can use `${#value}` to count the length of a variable in bash. And in your specific case where you simply want to know it its *not* empty you can use: `[ -n "$value" ]`

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same question recently. I wrote this small script called `printf-wrap` to achieve this feature, inspired by the top answer by @phobic. The reason why it is necessary is that the version of `column` on a user's workstaion may not have wrapping capability and he/she may not be authorized to install or update any packages either. (Yes, the user is me ...)

`printf-wrap` accepts exactly the **same input arguments** as `printf`, and **wrap smartly** the text within **every columns**. And you can use `tput` to adjust it to terminal width.

```
# printf-wrap
# Description:  Printf with smart word wrapping for every columns.
# Usage:        print-wrap "<format>" "<text>" "<text>" ...
function printf-wrap {
    # help info
    help_message="Usage: print-column-wrap \"<format>\" \"<text>\" \"<text>\" ..."
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^(-|--)?(h|help)$ ]] ; then echo "$help_message" ; return 0 ; fi 
    # parse argument
    format="$1"
    width=( $( echo "$format" | sed -r 's/%%|\\%//g' | sed -r 's/%/\n%/g' | sed -n -r 's/^%[^1-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/p' ) )
    shift
    text=( "$@" )
    error_message="Error: number of input text fields (${#text[@]}) MUST NOT EXCEED number of columns specified (${#width[@]}) !"
    if (( ${#text[@]} > ${#width[@]} )) ; then echo "$error_message" ; return 1 ; fi
    # printing
    while [ -n "$( echo "${text[@]}" | sed -r 's/\s+//g' )" ] ; do
        text_cut=()
        width_cut=()
        for i in ${!text[@]} ; do
            text[$i]="$( echo "${text[$i]}" | sed -r 's/^\s+//' )"
            if [[ "${text[$i]:${width[$i]}-1:2}" =~ [a-zA-Z0-9_]{2} ]] ; then
                text_cut[$i]="$( echo "${text[$i]:0:${width[$i]}}" | sed -r 's/\w+$//' )"
            else
                text_cut[$i]="${text[$i]:0:${width[$i]}}"
            fi
                width_cut[$i]=${#text_cut[$i]}
                text[$i]="${text[$i]:${width_cut[$i]}}"
        done
        printf "$format" "${text_cut[@]}"
    done
}
```

The ouput looks like the following.

```
$ printf-wrap "%-10s %-$(( $(tput cols) - 11 ))s\n" "key1" "This is the value for key1 with a very long text"
============ Terminal Width ============
key1       This is the value for key1   
           with a very long text
```

Hope this can help anyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was writing to both the screen and a file and was having difficulties in maintaining the tabbing.  I switched to spacing because it was absolutely the same between screen/file and linux/windows.  Here is a bit of the code that pads the field with spaces to make sure the next field is equal distance apart from each column item.  If you want to pad the beginning just move the space to the beginning of the variable instead of after it in the "sHeading=" line.  You could do the same with tabbing if you want.

```
# sHeading: The field I want to pad.
# iSpace:   The length I want the field
# use spacing instead of tabbing
# ensures string has 52 characters (padding the rest with spaces)

if [[ ${#sHeading} -ne $iSpace ]]; then
    i=$(($iSpace-${#sHeading}))
    while [[ $i -gt 0 ]]; do
        sHeading="${sHeading} "
        i=$(($i-1))
    done
fi
```

Comment: So I could call this for each column as sHeading for each line and then concatenate and echo the results per line..

Comment: But I would still end up with long lines that wrap and start at the beginning of the next line.